# populating a matrix with a list, where each vector in the list may be 1 - 7 elements [R]

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Say I have some ';' separated information in a vector, that I want to split apart, using strsplit. `data` contains information that looks like this:

```
[1] "k__Fungi; p__Ascomycota; c__Eurotiomycetes; o__unidentified; f__unidentified; g__unidentified; s__Eurotiomycetes sp"
[2] "k__Fungi; p__Basidiomycota; c__Agaricomycetes; o__Agaricales; f__Mycenaceae; g__unidentified; s__Mycenaceae sp"     
[3] "k__Fungi; p__Ascomycota"                                                                                            
[4] "None"                                                                                                               
[5] "k__Fungi; p__Glomeromycota; c__Glomeromycetes; o__Glomerales; f__Glomeraceae; g__Glomus; s__Glomus macrocarpum"     
[6] "k__Fungi; p__Basidiomycota; c__Agaricomycetes; o__Agaricales; f__Inocybaceae; g__Inocybe"
```

I use `strsplit` to separate out this information like this:

```
list<- strsplit(data,split=";")
```

the output of which is

```
[[1]]
[1] "k__Fungi"              " p__Ascomycota"        " c__Eurotiomycetes"    " o__unidentified"      " f__unidentified"      " g__unidentified"      " s__Eurotiomycetes sp"

[[2]]
[1] "k__Fungi"           " p__Basidiomycota"  " c__Agaricomycetes" " o__Agaricales"     " f__Mycenaceae"     " g__unidentified"   " s__Mycenaceae sp" 

[[3]]
[1] "k__Fungi"       " p__Ascomycota"

[[4]]
[1] "None"

[[5]]
[1] "k__Fungi"               " p__Glomeromycota"      " c__Glomeromycetes"     " o__Glomerales"         " f__Glomeraceae"        " g__Glomus"             " s__Glomus macrocarpum"

[[6]]
[1] "k__Fungi"           " p__Basidiomycota"  " c__Agaricomycetes" " o__Agaricales"     " f__Inocybaceae"    " g__Inocybe"
```

I then want to push this information into a matrix formatted to be the length of the original data object, and 7 named columns. I generate an empty matrix like this:

```
out<- matrix(nrow=(length(data)),ncol=7)
colnames(out)<-c("kingdom","phylum","class","order","family","genus","species")
```

The empty matrix ends up looking like this:

```
     kingdom phylum class order family genus species
[1,]      NA     NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
[2,]      NA     NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
[3,]      NA     NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
[4,]      NA     NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
[5,]      NA     NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
[6,]      NA     NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
```

I then want to insert the information from `list` into the matrix, such that if the first vector in the list has 7 elements, all 7 columns in row 1 will have entries. However, if a vector in the list only has two elements, then only the first two columns in that matrix row will have entries, and the rest will remain as `NA` values.

**NOTE: I am intentionally avoiding for loops. I had a for loop solution, but it fails when I scale to a data set with 100,000 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try

```
library(stringi)
m1 <- stri_list2matrix(list, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(m1) <- c("kingdom","phylum","class","order","family","genus","species")
```

Or instead of using `strsplit`, we can directly read it with `read.table`

```
read.table(text=data, sep=";", fill=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings='')
```

Or using the devel version of `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(list(data))[,tstrsplit(V1, '; ')]
```

Comment: the first solution works and is orders of magnitude faster than my for-loop! The second fails. I have `data.table` loaded, but copy/pasting `setDT(list(data))[,tstrsplit(V1, '; ')]` into R errors with `could not find function "tstrsplit"`

Comment: @colin It is the devel version as I mentioned.  `tstrsplit` is a new function.  You can find instructions to install the devel version [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: for sure. I just used these names to generalize the question. My actual script has more specific names.